# How does Custom User Control send data to Hosting Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have implemented a custom user control using c#. This control has a button.
Then the control is added to a WinForm Form1 which has list box.

The problem is : how can I add some value in the list box when i click the button in the user control?

Comment: raise an event from the usercontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to raise an event from the user control when you click the button, and then catch it in your form1.

You can do something like this :

**User Control**

```
public event EventHandler CLickFromUserControl;

private void click_event_on_the_button()
{
    //Null check makes sure the main page is attached to the event
    if (this.CLickFromUserControl != null)
       this.CLickFromUserControl(new object(), new EventArgs());
}
```

**Form1**

```
public MyApp()
{
     //USERCONTROL = your control with the CLickFromUserControl event
     this.USERCONTROL.CLickFromUserControl += new EventHandler(MyEventHandlerFunction_CLickFromUserControl);
}

public void MyEventHandlerFunction_CLickFromUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         //add the value here
}
```

You can pass more parameters to the event :

```
this.CLickFromUserControl(new object(), new EventArgs(), param1, param2);
```

And then in the form :

```
public void MyEventHandlerFunction_CLickFromUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e, string param 1, string param2)
{
         //add the value here
}
```

**OR**

You can create properties on your user control :

```
public string Value {
  get { return textBox1.Text; }
  set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

And then access it from the sender in the form's event.

You can check out how to build an event : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Vs didn'T recognize "CLickFromUserControl " in Form1.  It is like undefined under this -> this.USERCONTROL.CLickFromUserControl += new EventHandler(MyEventHandlerFunction_CLickFromUserControl);

Comment: Did you put : public event EventHandler CLickFromUserControl; in the user control ?

Comment: Works 100% ,, thanks alot . Small question plz. if now i have several components in my Custom Control. Now i am in Forms 1 and i want to know which control is clicked and maybe also read its Text Property!!how can i modify that?

Comment: What do you mean text property ? The text property of your user control ?

Comment: You can pass the property to the event ! I will update the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jonsey and @Vinc P. suggested, you should use **Event** to do your job.

Basically, the work flow is:

1. User triggers a click event **on the button**;
2. Custom User Control gets the event, handle it, then pass it to its parent, which is the form;
3. Form gets the event and handle it.

To achieve the workflow, we can do the following:

**In User Control**
We need to define delegate and event for the form to register:

```
public delegate void ButtonClickEventDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ButtonClickEventDelegate ButtonClick;
```

Next we need to register the **Button Click Event Handler**:

```
// in the custom user control constructor
public CustomUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Button.Click += ButtonClickHandler;
}
```

Next we need to define the behavior of **Button click** in the user control:

```
private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some handling if you have
    // now the important part, call the delegate function here, it will pass the handle to
    // the behavior defined in the main form:
    if (ButtonClick != null) ButtonClick(this, e);
}
```

Now we have finished the **User Control** part, next is about the **Hosting Form**.
The thing we need to do is simple: register and define the behavior of **ButtonClick**:

```
// in main form's constructor
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CustomUserControl.ButtonClick += UserControlButtonClickHandler();
}

private void UserControlButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add the value here
}
```

Ok, things done :)